how do i fix this :Error? You cannot add another key because the service account github-action-788739256 already contains the max number of keys: 10
Error: You cannot add another key because the service account github-action-788739256 already contains the max number of keys: 10.
how do i fix this error?
im working on a next.js project and trying to host it on firebase..
i tried creating a key or find out what 10 keys ive used but i did not find anything at all...
